# Access packages info from Netsuite packing slip freemarker

Tags: netsuite, packing

I'm just looking for some help.
I want to display the package descriptions with tracking numbers on the packing slip pdf/html templates.

Item Fulfillment > packageUpsList > packageUps > packageDescrUps, packageTrackingNumberUps

But I can't find what the freemarker script should be?

Below is my custom advanced pdf template.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
      tr {
        line-height: 32px;
      }
      th {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      td {
        font-size: 16px;
      }
</style>
</head>
<body header="nlheader" header-height="10%" footer="nlfooter" footer-height="0pt" padding="0.5in 0.5in 0in 0.5in" size="Letter">
<#assign curpage = 1>
<#list trackingnumbers?split(' ') as x>
    <h1 style="width: 100%; text-align: center; padding-top:25px; margin-bottom: 60px;"><b>Packing Slip</b></h1>
<div style="height:530px;"><#if salesorder.item?has_content>
<table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2">ITEM</th>
    <th colspan="1">QTY</th>
    <th colspan="6">DESCRIPTION</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="9" style="border-bottom: solid 2px black;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <#list salesorder.item as tranline>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">${tranline.item?split(' ')[0]}</td>
    <td colspan="1">${tranline.quantity}</td>
    <td colspan="6">${tranline.description}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list></table>
</#if></div>

<table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><tr>
    <td colspan="9" style="background-color: #666666; color: white; font-size: 24px; line-height:40px; text-indent: 10px;">NOTE: Supplies may be packed in between boxes.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="9" style="font-size: 30px; line-height:60px; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: solid 2px black;">Package : ${curpage} OF ${trackingnumbers?split(' ')?size}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5" style="padding-top:20px; text-align:left;"><barcode codetype="code128" showtext="false" value="${salesorder.tranid}" style="width: 400px; height:100px; position: relative; left: -40px;"/></td>
    <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 48px; line-height:140px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">${salesorder.tranid}</td>
    </tr></table>
<#assign curpage = curpage + 1>
</#list>
</body>
</pdf>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just `package` e.g.

```
<#list record.package as pkg>${pkg.packagetrackingnumber} </#list>
```